# How to link/import css into ajax?

Tags: php, css, ajax

I want to create a tree menu inside my PHP code within an ajax php file. The problem is that there are classes used inside the code of the tree :

```
$html .= '<li><span style="min-width:200px" class="folder">';
$html .= $ret[$c]["class_menu_lib"] . "</span>";
$html .= $this->lireFils($user_id, $ret[$c]["class_menu_code"]);;
$html .= "</li>";
```

So how to link the css file into the ajax code ?

Answer (score 1):

Ajax just means "making HTTP requests from JavaScript".

If you want to add a stylesheet to a page, then you do it the same way you add anything else to the page.

You either place it in the initial HTML, or you add it to the DOM later (as you are doing with the HTML you are retrieving via Ajax).

Comment: The problem is that I call the ajax in the $(document).ready() of the page ! The css are already linked in that page but ajax does not seem to recognise them !!!

Comment: Then either (1) You aren't linking it correctly, (2) Your JavaScript is deleting the stylesheet or (3) The stylesheet doesn't match the HTML correctly

Answer (score 1):

the same way, as in html

```
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/your_css.css" />';
```

Comment: Can I write it inside an ajax file ?

Comment: You can write it to ajax file, but it can also be in html file, because return of ajax will be places in some element in your html, and there are already preloaded your css files.

Answer (score 0):

So long as the html page into which you end up inserting the html has a reference to the necessary CSS file(s), it should work correctly.

With that in mind, if you want your AJAX code to work with the CSS if applied to an arbitrary page which may not reference that CSS file, then you could set your AJAX code to append a reference to the CSS file in the `head` of the page where you're inserting the rest of your code.

```
$('head').html(
    $('head').html() +
    '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/my.css" />'
);
```

Comment: Do I write that inside the ajax file or where ?

Comment: You need the stylesheet reference to be added whenever you make that particular AJAX call. So, first off I'm assuming you're using jQuery. Second, you could put it inside your AJAX function, or wherever makes the most sense based on your code.